# Clean install Windows 10 and then using Windows 7/8.1 serial

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

According to this article (http://news.softpedia.com/news/windows-10-creators-update-can-be-activated-with-windows-7-and-8-1-product-keys-514679.shtm), I am able to use my windows 7 pro OEM key on a clean install Windows 10.

I guess my question is: do I need to have upgraded my windows 7 to 10 previously? Or I can just go from activated Windows 7 pro to a clean install (and activated) Windows 10?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Windows 10 will only activate with a Windows 7 or Windows 8 product key, if you installed it BEFORE the July 29th 2016 deadline, otherwise while the installation environment will accept the license the installation will not actually activate.

Answer (score 1):

The license code from previous Windows should be fine for Windows 10. But you may need to make some changes to the installation media to install proper version, as you must use the same version as it was (Home/Pro). To do that you may need to edit (create) file `\sources\ei.cfg` and put this there:

```
[EditionID]
Professional
[Channel]
Retail
```